# Case Management Contact Name

Tags: case, formula-field, email2case

I would like to use Users Contact  variables(Custom Object) to extract information when Email to Case triggers instead using Contact Name (Standard Field). Apart implementing Case type Formula, is there any other alternatives similar to Contact Name functionality? Inclusive being able to click on the User directing to User Profile similar to Contacts.

Comment: Could you be more clear about your question?

Comment: In Case, we have standard Contacts capturing information via email to case. As for change we wanted to implement Users instead Contacts for Custom field to be enabled for email to case information auto population

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can just substitute the main Contact field with a User lookup, but there may be a workaround with some custom code.

You could write a trigger that automatically creates/updates/deletes Contacts when Users are inserted/updated/deactivated.  Those Contact records should have a lookup to the user they are associated with.

That way when a Case comes in it automatically picks up the contact from the email address field and then you can use a workflow to populate your own User field.

The hardest part of this would be the trigger that maintains the Contact records, but I don't think it would be that difficult.